# Сортировка данных

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Не могу отсортировать выведенные данные из mysql в обратном порядке.  
Вывожу при помощи while.  
Пишу в запросе `ORDER BY score DESK` - цикл не идет, и значения из бд не достать.  
Убираю `DESK` - цикл работает, но значения не в том порядке, в котором мне надо.  
Мне нужен порядок вывода - `3 2 1`.
А получается только `1 2 3`.

```
        $sel = 'SELECT * FROM `players` 
        ORDER BY `last_connect`
        LIMIT 0, 10';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DESC а не DESK